# Laravel Eloquent - Get many-relationship of many-relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Assume the following structure:

A `user` has many `projects`. A `project` has many `tasks`.

Goal: I want to get all `tasks` of a certain `$user`.  What is the most elegant way to achieve this?

What I am currently using is a big, non intuitive function chain that returns a collection instead of a collection builder instance:

```
return $user->projects()->with('tasks')->get()->pluck('tasks')->flatten();
```

This is what the relationships look like:

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}

class Project extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your relationship is  not `manyToMany` its `hasManyThrough` relationship, do you post these 3 model please?

Comment: @sta I've added the relationships to my question. They are one-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)** relationship is a bit complicated to understand a provide shortcut way to access data of another mode relation. 
In your **User** model make relationship like this way :

```
public function tasks()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
     Task::class,
     Project::class,
     'user_id', // Foreign key on projects table...
     'project_id', // Foreign key on tasks table...
     'id', // Local key on users table...
     'id' // Local key on projects table...
   );
}
```